# Google spreadsheet relative row numbering + skip empty cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Using Google spreadsheet, I need a column to show relative row numbering, so that:

1. Spreadsheet rows can be moved around, and numbering stays relative (meaning that if I move row number 12 between rows 4 and 5, this row becomes number 5, previous 5 becomes 6, etc.)
2. Using a condition based upon a cell value in a given row, the row numbering cell may be empty (or not); if empty, that row number is being skipped, and numbering takes back up in the next row where the condition is unmatched.

Here is an example:

```
| Row nbr |  B col. | [Explanation]                       |
|---------|:-------:|-------------------------------------|
| R01     | Value 1 |                                     |
| R02     | Value 1 |                                     |
| R03     | Value 2 |                                     |
|         | Value 3 | Col. B value = 3 => Col. A is empty |
| R04     | Value 2 | Numbering takes up                  |
| R05     | Value 1 |                                     |
|         | Value 3 | Col. B value = 3 => Col. A is empty |
| R06     | Value 2 | Numbering takes up                  |
| ETC.    |         |                                     |
```

Here, the condition (to skip numbering) would be "IF corresponding B cell = Value 3" (then skip numbering)

Right now, I'm using a formula that matches requirement #1 above:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A"))-9
```

(The trailing "-9" is just an offset so numbering can start at 01 from row 10).

So basically, I need to adapt (or change) this code so that besides relative numbering, for row N, if corresponding B column cell value = XYZ, then A column cell is empty (vs. numbered): that row is being skipped, and numbering takes back up from N on the next row where the B cell value ≠ XYZ.

Here's a [Google spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VSMxKGTCaFIVXo8ozH8hZYlhKm9ejdwROjO3rKBO_2M/edit#gid=0).

Many TIA's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend not to use `ROW()` with explicitly specified offset in formula because should you delete/add rows above your table, your will have to adjust formulas in all cells. Here's my solution (column `A:A` is row numbers, `B:B` - values, start adding formula in cell `A10`):

```
=IF($B10="Value 3","",ROWS($B$10:$B10)-COUNTIF($B$10:$B10,"Value 3"))
```

Or if you insist on relative rows (change `10` to your offset from top):

```
=IF(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="Value 3","",ROWS(INDIRECT("B"&10&":B"&ROW()))-COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B"&10&":B"&ROW()),"Value 3"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I tried entering the formula within the A10 cell on the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VSMxKGTCaFIVXo8ozH8hZYlhKm9ejdwROjO3rKBO_2M/edit#gid=0) and it returns an error.

Another point I'm not getting is that if I use absolute cell referencing, how can I paste in into 100 rows and adapt absolute reference to each cell?

NB: In this case we won't need to add rows, just to be able to move rows around (and keep relative numbering, for this too I'm not getting how absolute reference will work).

Many thanks again.

Comment: You seem to have different list separator. Change all commas `,` in my formula to `;`. Formula absolute reference only in range start `$B$10`. Range end is not fixed so the range extends as you drag the formula down.

Comment: AH, the only problem is that if I move row R08 to line 13, it doesn"t get renumbered. See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VSMxKGTCaFIVXo8ozH8hZYlhKm9ejdwROjO3rKBO_2M/edit#gid=0). R08 should be R03, and subsequent rows updated. Any idea?

Comment: Formula got broken. Copy it from another cell. In general, you shouldn't move formulas but rather copy them and delete from source.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm being clear: what I need is that a row can be dragged and dropped from one line to another, and get renumbered according to its new position, then subsequent rows be renumbered accordingly, without the user having to modify the formula. If I copy the formula from R10 and paste it into (what should be) then R03 will be numbered R10; subsequent rows are numbered correctly. Sorry if I'm being dense and/or unclear.

Comment: I started back from your formula here, replicated in all cells (by dragging), then moved up R08 and it doesn't get renumbered.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your time. I'll upvote your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: FWIW, I posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362585/google-spreadsheet-relative-rows-numbering-based-on-multiple-conditions) to extend that same logic to multiple conditions (IF "Value 2" OR "Value 3" vs. just "Value 3").

Comment: Using INDIRECT on a range like that to isolate the cells above is very clever.  Well done!  I will try to remember that trick in the future. :)